# Find the general solution in integer

Tags: integers

I tried this but my friend has a different answer [image]

Did I make any mistakes?

Comment: What do you have to find?

Comment: General solution in integer and least positive integral solution

Comment: Least positive integral solution? But how can we find least positive solution of two variables.

Comment: @LoveInvariants the way it is written, given any solution with $x,y > 0,$ we get another solution $(x-17,y-41).$ The least solution is the last one before one of the variables becomes negative or zero.

Comment: An [introduction to posting mathematical expressions](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) here may prove interesting and useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to solve $$41x-17y=8.$$
This is equivalent to solving $$41x \equiv 8 \mod 17.$$
As $41 \equiv 7$ and $7^{-1} \equiv 5 \mod 17$ we get

$$7x \equiv 8 \mod 17$$ $$x \equiv 5\cdot 8 \mod 17$$  $$x \equiv 6  \mod 17.$$

This means $x-6 = 17k$ for integer $t$ or $$x=17t+6.$$  It is clear that $x$ is positive so long as $t \geq 0.$  We can plug to get $$41(17t+6)-17y=8$$ which simplifies to $$41t+14=y.$$  This shows us that for every possible $r\geq 0$ we have a positive $y$.

Notice that there is more than one way to write this answer.  I could have instead taken $x=17t+23$ for $t \geq -1$ or $x=17t-11$ for $t \geq 1$.